# t-sql query to verify if any server doesn´t exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How could I verify if any server in a list of server doesn´t exist in my table ?

( I need verify if server1, server2 or server3 doesn´t exist in my Nodes table).

I´m using sql server 2008.

Comment: What does your nodes table look like?  What have you tried?

Comment: I was trying this with no success:     SELECT 
Nodes.Caption 
 FROM 
Nodes
 WHERE  not exists (select nodes.caption from nodes where nodes.caption like 
'server1',
'server2',
'server3')

Comment: What does your nodes table look like?

Comment: My nodes table haves NodeID, Caption and location names.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, this should work.  But the question is rather vague... are you literally looking for server1, 2, and 3 or is this going to be a table valued parameter or come from some other source?  A little more background would help a lot.

```
;WITH servers AS (
SELECT 'server1' AS server UNION 
SELECT 'server2' AS server UNION 
SELECT 'server3' AS server)

SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    servers
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Nodes ON (Nodes.Caption = servers.server)
WHERE 
    (Nodes.Caption IS NULL)
```

Comment: Or, for a non-`NULL` solution: `SELECT server FROM servers EXCEPT SELECT caption AS server FROM nodes`

Comment: Output from this query is empty, cause I doesn´t have these 3 servers in my table, but I´d like to see these 3 servers in query´s output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did this change, and now it´s working fine !                                                 WITH servers AS (
SELECT 'server1' AS server UNION 
SELECT 'server2' AS server UNION 
SELECT 'server3' AS server)


SELECT server FROM servers EXCEPT SELECT caption AS server FROM nodes